# Bieber Roast Jokes

Tags: comedy-central-roast

In the Justin Bieber Roast on Comedy Central, Justin remarks that Natasha Legero did not shoot out ping-pong balls like snoop promised. Can someone explain the significance of this? I don't understand the reference.

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure how to answer this one in a family friendly way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In certain establishments, notably in those areas with a reputation for bawdy licentiousness you can go to see live sex shows where a female performer will expel ping-pong balls from an intimate body part.

Justin Bieber was presumably claiming that he was promised such a performance (from Natasha Legero) in return for attending his roast, something he might not have otherwise done given how little he would enjoy it.

The joke itself is a variant on the classic ["You said there would be x", "yeah, I lied"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrNrLly1vvM) formula.

Answer (score 0):

Roasts are for people to insult each other...

The joke is that Natasha is such a dirty, filthy woman, that she is able to do that. Also there is a possibilty that she did  it FOR Snoop at one point.

Also, if you're even in Japan. Check that, or the banana lady out...